# CentOs Vmware networking

Tags: centos, windows

I have CentOS server installed inside vmware for testing puprose.
For some strange reason When it comes up it won't get IP address properly

So, I have to manually use 'ifdown' and 'dhclient' every time it comes up.
I only do have problem with internet running interfaces and not any other interface.

Comment: Do you have the latest VMWare tools installed in the CentOS vm?

Answer (score 4):

Is this `CentOS 6`? If so I got burned by this one as well. Check out the [official CentOS 6 FAQ](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-b67e85d98f0e9f1b599358105c551632c6ff7c90).

The issue is that `NetworkManager` is now responsible for the `eth0` device and by default it's disabled. During installation you can configure `eth0` so that it will start up automatically, but the default is that it doesn't.

If you need to configure this after you've setup the system you can follow the steps in the FAQ which tell you exactly how to setup the `eth0`.

The nuts of the fix are that you need to edit this `eth0` configuration file, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, and make sure that the `ONBOOT` line is enabled, i.e., `ONBOOT="yes"`.

Here's a couple of screenshots of where to configure this during the CentOS installation. I totally missed it the first couple of times.

[image: Installation, configure networking for ONBOOT 1/3]

[image: Installation, configure networking for ONBOOT 2/3]

[image: Installation, configure networking for ONBOOT 3/3]